# I am not able to create two notifications with different time even using two classes using broadcast receivers

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-broadcastreceiver

This is the main class where I am trying to call both methods for creating notifications

`shownotificationAtNight(hour,min)`, 
`shownotificationAtMorning(hour,min)`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        shownotificationAtNight(22,21);
        shownotificationAtMorning(10,22);

    }

    private void shownotificationAtNight(int hour,int min) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,min);

        if(calendar.getTime().compareTo(new Date()) < 0) {calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);}

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }

    private void shownotificationAtMorning(int hour,int min) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,min);

        if(calendar.getTime().compareTo(new Date()) < 0) {calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);}

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MorningAlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Then the receiver class are as follow with MID creating random number for different notifications

```
public class MorningAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
        int MID  = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
             long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
             NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                                                       .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

             Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ToTask.class);
                notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

             PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


             Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


              NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context).setSmallIcon(meg)
                .setContentTitle("Todays Alarm")
                .setContentText("Get done and add new tasks").setSound(alarmSound)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
              notificationManager.notify(MID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
              MID++;
        }
}
```

The other class receiver

```
class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    int MID  = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ToTask.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context).setSmallIcon(meg)
                .setContentTitle("Tommorow Plan")
                .setContentText("Events To be Performed").setSound(alarmSound)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
        notificationManager.notify(MID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
        MID++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit your Manifest accordingly?

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"></receiver>
```